# remove horizontal black line in a grayscale image

Tags: python, image-processing, grayscale, imagej, fiji

I have this image that has a continuous black horizontal line, and I need to remove it as a first step in enhancing it.
is there a way to remove it using imageJ/Fiji or python, such as a library or a plug in?

I understand the concept of using a mask of this horizontal line and using it to merge median filtered/blurred input with the original input. but I don't know how to apply it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured using the 'inpaint' function and a mask of the horizontal line
output = cv2.inpaint(im,mask,3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)

the result

[image]